# Assign data in a SELECT>CASE statement, then use in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I'm using a CASE statement in the SELECT to assign the value of the 'Team' column.  I then would like to be able to use the value I assign in the WHERE clause.  See my sample query below for an example.

In my simplified example, I know I could use the s.id value in my WHERE clause and get the desired result, but I have a more complex scenario I'm working with where it would be helpful to actually use the string I assign in the WHERE clause.

Is this possible?  I'm using MS SQL Server 2012.

In the searching I've done, I've not found any definitive information, one way or the other.  Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT s.tickedNum, s.ticketSummary,'Team' =
      CASE
         WHEN s.id in (100) THEN 'Team A'
         WHEN s.id in (200) THEN 'Team B'
         WHEN s.id in (300) THEN 'Team C'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
      END,
FROM supportTable s
WHERE
'Team' = 'Team B'
```

Comment: Can't do that.  You need a subquery or CTE instead.  You cannot use an alias defined in the `select` in its corresponding `where` clause.

Comment: You also can use cross apply if you really want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yoiu can't reference aliases in a `WHERE` clause becasue the `WHERE` calues typically is evaluated *before* the column expressions to determine how to collect the proper rows.

You could either repeat the `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause or use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT s.tickedNum, s.ticketSummary,
      CASE
         WHEN s.id in (100) THEN 'Team A'
         WHEN s.id in (200) THEN 'Team B'
         WHEN s.id in (300) THEN 'Team C'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
      END AS Team,
FROM supportTable s
) inner
WHERE
inner.Team = 'Team B'
```

Since your where clause only hits one possible `CASE` you could also do

```
SELECT s.tickedNum, s.ticketSummary,
      CASE
         WHEN s.id in (100) THEN 'Team A'
         WHEN s.id in (200) THEN 'Team B'
         WHEN s.id in (300) THEN 'Team C'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
      END AS Team,
FROM supportTable s
WHERE s.id = 200  /* equivalent to 'Team B' */
```

Comment: Not "*typically* evaluated before ...", but "***always*** evaluated before ...*".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I try to avoid absolutes when it comes to implementation-specific SQL answers, as there are so many variations that it's entirely possible that some frings platform evaulates the query in a different order.  But you are right.  In most (if not all) platforms, the where clause is evaluated first.

Comment: In SQL the WHERE must be evaluated first - for exactly the same reason that the Select() follows the Where() in LINQ: the mathematical foundation of the language requires it. I do however take your point about being cautious with absolutes.

Answer (score 0):

Any operation completed in its previous phase is visible to its next logical phase.So the order goes like **from ,where,group by ,having,select ,order by ,top**..You can see defintive list from the Itzik Ben Gan [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)

In your case the assignment of teamA,TeamB is done after where clause completion.So where has no idea about them..

If you want to do ,you need to refer them in CTE or some derived table or else you can use cross apply..

Just for demonstration.This is not needed in this case even though execution plan is simpler featuring hash match (will go for merge join if you have indexes on ID) and a compute scalar

```
create table test
(
id int,
name varchar(3)
)


insert into test
select 1,'abc'
union all
select 2,'cde'

select id,case id when 1 then 'abc'
                   when 2 then 'cde'
                   else null end  'values'
from test t1
cross apply
(select case id when 1 then 'abc'
                   when 2 then 'cde'
                   else null end  'values_apply' from test t2 where t1.id=t2.id) a
where a.values_apply='abc'
```

**Output:**

```
id value
1   abc
```